# Eiffel is_equal() function

Tags: compare, comparison, eiffel

I'm trying to understand better the function *is_equal()* defined in class **COMPARABLE**.

I would like to know in which case, for an object **o** the function call ***o.is_equal(o)*** gives *false*.

I know that this function, differently from ***=***, not just compares the address of objects, but also the values of all their attributes.

Following this definition I was pretty sure that such a call would always give *true*, since we're comparing the same object.

I would really appreciate if someone could explain me what's wrong in my thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment an origin of feature `is_equal` is class `ANY`, not `COMPARABLE`. Class `COMPARABLE` redefines the feature and adds a postcondition `trichotomy` that specifies properties of equality in terms of inequality (or, in terms of a query `is_less` to be more precise). So to understand what's going on, let's look at the origin.

Class `ANY` has an invariant

```
reflexive_equality: standard_is_equal (Current)
```

At the same time feature `is_equal` has a postcondition

```
consistent: standard_is_equal (other) implies Result
```

Combining the two (even without knowing what is `standard_is_equal`) we can derive a new invariant

```
new_reflexive_equality: is_equal (Current)
```

that should be valid for every object. So as soon as `o` in the expression yields the same object all the time (e.g. if it is a variable, and not a function that returns different objects at every call), **`o.is_equal (o)`  should always produce `True`**. Of course, one can try to redefine `is_equal` to return `False`, but this would break the contract of the feature.

In real life the comparison is usually `o1.is_equal (o2)` that can be `True` or `False` depending on values of `o1` and `o2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, the point is that in an old exam of Bertrand Meyer regarding Eiffel, the statement "For an object o, the feature call o.is_equal(o) always returns True" is false.

Comment: This means that there should be some cases where the statement is false, but I cannot find which it could be since I came at the same solution you came!

Comment: @Ergo: If that was really old, there could be no postcondition as in the current version and one could redefine `is_equal` to return `False` or even to.change the object under the hood.